# ckeditor not showing in JavaScript insertRow() table

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

This is my JavaScript function for `insertRow()` in my table:

```
  <script>

  function myFunction() {

    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

    cell1.innerHTML = '{{ Form::text('title_detail[]', '', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Detail Title','required' => 'required')) }}';
    cell2.innerHTML = '{{  Form::textarea('description_detail[]', '', array('class' => 'form-control ckeditor','placeholder' => 'Detail Deskripsi','required' => 'required')) }}';
    cell3.innerHTML = '{{  Form::number('sort_order_detail[]', '', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Detail Sort Order','required' => 'required')) }}';
    cell4.innerHTML = '<button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>';

  }
</script>
```

When I click the button, it's added to my table, but the `ckeditor` class is not showing up.

Comment: there should be an obvious error in the console. it's most probably due to the usage of the single and double quote together for the `innerHTML`..

Comment: the quote actually right, i've test it. the form showing and not error, but the ckeditor not showing

Comment: can you please try commenting code for setting `.innerHTML` on cell1,cell2,cell3 and see if that works ?